# Changing webpage encoding in iOS

Tags: ios, web-browser, web-browsing, encoding

Some webpages are encoded differently and not well-configured, so they may show up completely jumbled. One example is this page, originally in Japanese:

http://immanuel.sakura.ne.jp/hoby/osakaben/osakaben.htm

On desktop one can simply ask the browser to reload the page with a different encoding, but I don't see this option in many iOS browsers. Is there an iOS browser out there that allows the user to manually select the encoding?

Comment: Ana luck with that site if you run iOS in Japanese?   I recently looked at a bunch of iOS browers and could not find one with text encoding choices either.

Comment: @TomGewecke Thanks for the suggestion! Changing the system language doesn't work, but it does work if you change the browser language to Japanese (for both Safari and Firefox, and likely more)...

Comment: @Rethliopuks How do you change the browser language?

Comment: @xji if this is still relevant for you -- I meant going into Settings and find the menu for the specific app. There you can change the language of the app.

Comment: @Rethliopuks how do I change the language for a specific app? Safari, Chrome, preferably. Edit: found it after re-reading your reply! Thanks. But example page above still garbled for me.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with Aloha browser set to Japanese, but Chrome keeps resetting to English even after restarting my iPhone. That said, your solution should be posted as the answer @Rethliopuks!

Comment: @Rethliopuks Changing Safari to Japanese worked. Thanks! Maybe you can post it as an answer here.

Answer (score 0):

A trick I often use is to go into the address bar to edit the page URL, adding `cache:` to the start of the URL so it begins `cache:https://`. This views the current page through the Google cache and the encoded text will display correctly. It doesn't work for every page, as Google don't cache every page.

Otherwise, I'm still searching for a modern replacement for an old iOS app "Character Encoding Web Utility" that was never updated to work on modern iOS.

Comment: This does work if you have google.com as a search engine or if you are using Chrome